# How to setup responsive design for UL elemeet

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to work on the responsive design with bootstrap for the ul elements.

I have html like:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class='row'>
         <ul>
             <li class='item'></li>
             <li class='item'></li>
             <li class='item'></li>
             <li class='item'></li>  
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item{
    background-color:red;
}
```

the elements looks fine with large width

```
 ---   ---    ---    ---
|   | |   |  |   |  |   |
 ---   ---    ---    ---
```

but not the smaller width

```
 --
|  | 
 --  
 --
|  | 
 --  
 --
|  | 
 --  
 --
|  | 
 --
```

I want to have smaller width for my li when it's in smaller screen and I want my li line up horizontally. Is that something you guys can help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Couldn't you just set your li widths as a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#my_list{
  width:100%;
}

#my_list li {
   width:300px;
   transition:ease-in-out 300ms all;
   display:inline-block;
   float:left; // dont forget to use a clearfix or similar method on the #my_list element
}


@media (max-width:320){
   #my_list li{
      width:150px;
      display:block;
   }
}
```

Something like this should be what you're looking for, hope I was able to help, if I didn't explain this clearly or was off the mark, please feel free to let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use percentages for responsive designs; Look at this example, if you play around with the width on the UL then that kinda represents a screen width
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGGJL/1/)

```
ul {
    width: 500px; /* This could be the screen width (100%) */
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.item{
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 1%;
    width: 23%; /* less width to compensate for margin */ 
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```